# How to determine where an exception is being rescued in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Some background: I have some Ruby code in a large codebase (Rails) that raises an exception under certain conditions. The exception however does not "occur" as expected, it is silently discarded. I assume that some other code (a gem) rescues the exception, maybe accidentally.

How can I determine *where* that exception is being rescued?

I do have full control over the exception. So maybe there's a way for an exception to know when or that it is being rescued?

Contrived example:

```
# code outside my control
def foo
  yield
rescue
end

def black_box(&block)
  foo(&block)
end
```

---

```
# my code
black_box do
  puts 'about to raise'
  raise
  puts 'never gets here'
end
```

Output:

```
about to raise
```

So the exception was rescued. How can I identify (from within "my code") that it was rescued in `foo`?

Comment: You could assume that the foreign gem does _something_ with the exception, not just silently skip it. Try to put breakpoints to `#message`, `#cause` etc and check for unintended breaks. When lucky, you’ll get the caller on top of the stack.

Comment: @mudasobwa indeed, that worked! The exception was rescued by Rails itself due to `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false` in an acceptance test.

Comment: Cool. Rails do too much magic, that’s why I prefer COBOL :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of (right now) is manual debugging/inspection.

When you're about to raise that exception you'd like to track, inspect current `caller`. This gives you a call stack. Now visit each line/method in your editor and look for rescues that are too much greedy.

As for more "automatic" ways, I don't see any. Ruby exceptions don't have `on_rescue` callbacks or anything like that, so they can't know they're being rescued.

Comment: A call stack of 115 lines :-(

Comment: @Stefan: you're lucky, it's a small one :)

Comment: Bummer, `TracePoint` doesn't help either, it has a `:raise` event, but no `:rescue`.

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, that was the first thing I checked. :)

Comment: This manual debugging method is actually quite fast. I use iTerm2 which allows me to command-click `filename:lineno` patterns to open the file in my editor, so I can easily click through the `caller` array to find the culprit.

Comment: @Stefan: I also use iterm2 and I never do that, but good to know!

Comment: It's hidden under Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Semantic History.

Answer (score 1):

*[after 3 years, I'm answering my own question here]*

At least in MRI, `rescue` is handled just like `when` in a `case` statement!

For example,

```
begin
  # ...
rescue A, B
  # ...
rescue C
  # ...
rescue
  # ...
end
```

is evaluated like:

```
case exception
when A, B
  # ...
when C
  # ...
when StandardError
  # ...
end
```

Under the hood, both of the above execute: (until a match is found)

```
A === exception
B === exception
C === exception
StandardError === Exception
```

with `===` being [`Module#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) because `A`, `B`, `C`, and `StandardError` are classes.

That `===` call can be used to track down a potential `rescue`, e.g. by overriding `Module#===` in `Exception`: (where it becomes a class method)

```
# foo.rb

def foo
  yield
rescue
end

def black_box(&block)
  foo(&block)
end
```

```
class Exception
  def self.===(other)
    cl = caller_locations[0]
    puts "#{cl.path}:#{cl.lineno} - #{$!.inspect}"
    super
  end
end

require_relative 'foo.rb'

black_box do
  puts 'about to raise'
  raise 'error message'
  puts 'never gets here'
end
```

Output:

```
about to raise
foo.rb:5 - #<RuntimeError: error message>
```

[`TracePoint`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/TracePoint.html) could also be used to intercept the method call:

```
TracePoint.trace(:c_call) do |tp|
  if tp.defined_class == Module && tp.method_id == :=== && tp.self <= Exception
    puts "#{tp.path}:#{tp.lineno} - #{$!.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! Did it take 3 years to solve this problem? :)